# For ELK,sometimes Logstash says “no such index”, how to set automatic create index in ES while “no such index”?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I found some pb with ELK, can anyone help me?

- logstash  2.4.0
- elasticsearch 2.4.0
- 3 elasticsearch instance for cluster

some time logstash warning:

> “ "status"=>404, "error"=>{"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such index",  ...”,

and it doesn't work. curl -XGET ES indices, it truly not have the index.
when this happen, I must kill -9  logstash, and start it again, then it can create a index in ES and it works ok again.

So, my question is how to set automatic create index in ES while “no such index”?

My logstash conf is:

```
input {
tcp {
port => 10514
codec => "json"
}
}


output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => [ "9200.xxxxxx.com:9200" ]
index => "log001-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your input?

Comment: Elasticsearch will create the index automatically if possible.  Check the ES logs for any errors.

Comment: there is no other error in ES logs, only like :  [2016-10-11 11:27:42,597][WARN ][shield.transport         ] [log-c001] Transport response handler not found of id [163958]